# WSO2 API Manager 1.6.0 - Distributed environment blocks each other on start

Tags: wso2

Update #2 to reflect the comments....
I have tried correcting for this issue launching the services varous ways...

```
#./wso2server.sh start

#./wso2server.sh -Dprofile=api-key-manager

#nohup ./wso2server.sh -Dprofile=api-key-manager &
```

Unfortuneately the errors have started occurring regardless.

Earlier post below...

Please note this is an edit...didn't want to post yet another question...
So now I'm really confused.  After upgrading WSO2 AM (API Manager) 1.6.0 and the problem persisting I decided to split up the services into Key Manager, Gateway, Store, and Publisher.
So now I have:
I have one server running the store and publisher on different ports.
I have another server running the gateway and keymanager on different ports.

The first service I started was Key Manager... which failed to start with:

```
2014-01-22 18:09:41,786 [-] [Timer-2]  WARN CarbonServerManager Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:
2014-01-22 18:09:41,788 [-] [Timer-2]  WARN CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.mediation.configadmin-4.2.0
2014-01-22 18:09:41,789 [-] [Timer-2]  WARN CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway-1.2.1
2014-01-22 18:09:41,789 [-] [Timer-2]  WARN CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin-4.2.1
2014-01-22 18:09:41,790 [-] [Timer-2]  WARN CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.localentry-4.2.0
```

Which is confusing to me since the Key Manager should not rely on the other components in AM.  It only connects to the APIMGT_DB which I've added in api-manager.xml
    jdbc/WSO2AM_DB

Any advice?

Comment: Usually this issue happens due to lack of performance in terms of memory and network. Can you please try a fresh pack of api manager on the same node (without any configuration changes) and update the question with the results?

Comment: @DarRay Same issue after installing and config of AM 1.6: 2014-01-22 14:15:50,097 [-] [Timer-2]  WARN CarbonServerManager Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items: WARN CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.mediation.configadmin-4.2.0
WARN CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway-1.2.1
WARN CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin-4.2.1
WARN CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.localentry-4.2.0

Comment: When you say split up, did you remove any features from the API Manager.

Comment: @KasunBG I did not remove any features. I copied the API Manager zip extraction into different folders (one for gateway, one for key manager). I configured each, and then started using the -Dprofile setting. -Dprofile=api-key-manager

Comment: @Gammonster Got it. It starts fine for me with -Dprofile=api-key-manager in AM 1.5. Didn't check the 1.6 yet. I guess you can start the server without specifying the profile for now to continue with the development.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a wild suggestion that you can tryout. I re-produced your issue frequently in APIM 1.6 server start-up, and after this modification I haven't seen this error anymore. So, may be this would work for you too.

1. Open the jar file, synapse-core_2.1.2.wso2v3.jar, at APIM_HOME/repository/components/plugins/. You can use a archive openers like file-roller.
2. Open the file at META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.
3. Search for the text, javax.xml.soap;version="0.0.0" . Replace it with - javax.xml.soap;version="1.0.0" . (The difference is in the version)
4. Save the file, and restart the server.

Comment: I have had it occur one time out of 5 so far after making the recommended change.  However, this is much better than the high % I was seeing prior.  I still don't understand what causes this issue, but restarting different components (in my dist. env.) seems to fix it.  In my stand alone environment it happened very consistently until I tried your change.

Comment: Great.. to add to this, you should probably create a patch folder, say, APIM_HOME/repository/components/patches/patch0555/, and copy the modified jar there. Otherwise, you might lose the change if you try to add another patch.

Comment: As I found out it was an OSGi 'class space' issue related to the javax.xml.soap java package. Both org.eclipse.osgi, and geronimo-saaj bundles were exporting the said package. Read more here if you are interested - http://njbartlett.name/2011/02/09/uses-constraints.html

Comment: Well, it appears this didn't resolve the issue.  I've had it occur 2 more times in 3 restarts.  I had to restart 2 times before the error cleared...I'm reading the above post.

Comment: I'm not sure I get how the 'uses' article applies.  Given the situation described there I would expect to always have the issue, not sometimes, as I can't sometimes have a 'uses' constraint and then other times not have a 'uses' constraint.  My errors imply that OSGi is waiting on other services that fail to start...although I can't see logs that say why.

Comment: This becomes intermittent because the synapse-core gets wired to the javax.xml.soap package from one of two bundles (org.eclipse.osgi seemingly random manner. It works if synapse-core got bound to geronimo-saaj bundle (ie. javax.xml.soap;version="1.0.0"). You have start-up time of more than two minutes initially even for a successful start-up since OSGi container was working real hard to wire the bundles correctly. The solution I suggested forces synapse-core to bound to the geronimo-saaj.

Comment: I have three people (including me) who said this solution worked for them. Can you make sure that your change to synapse-core didn't get reverted somehow? Creating a patch as said in a previous comment is the proper way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I guess I'm suprised the bind order is random. The update is still in place for the jar file. The MANIFEST.MF file still reads: ...javax.xml.parsers;resolution:=optio nal,javax.xml.soap;version="1.0.0",javax.xml.stream;resolu... However, I suppose it is possible there is another binding issue besides this one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, after we moved from AM 1.5.0 to 1.6.0, the issue disappears.

Comment: Same issue after 1.6.0 install/config: 2014-01-22 14:15:50,097 [-] [Timer-2]  WARN CarbonServerManager Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:
WARN CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.mediation.configadmin-4.2.0
WARN CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway-1.2.1
WARN CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin-4.2.1
WARN CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.localentry-4.2.0

Comment: Confirmed, another environment of us has the same issue. Does anyone from WSO2 has a light on this: 

[2014-01-23 15:23:50,722]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.mediation.configadmin-4.2.0
[2014-01-23 15:23:50,723]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway-1.2.1
[2014-01-23 15:23:50,723]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin-4.2.1